# ruby on rails best_in_place gem field name change on error display

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, best-in-place

So i have setup the **best_in_place** gem [[https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place]](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place) but i am facing a little problem when my column i try to edit looks like `title_name` and when an error occurs it shows it like

```
'title_name can't be blank,is too short (minimum is 1 characters)'
```

I would like to edit the way the gem handles the error display so it will replace the `_` with `space` and maybe make it a little `user-friendly`

**EDIT:**

**checking the response** i get via **Firebug** is:

```
{"title_name":["can't be blank","is too short (minimum is 1 characters)"]}
```

**where in the gem demo** http://bipapp.heroku.com/users/59

```
["Last name has invalid length","Last name can't be blank"]
```

which is a bit different...

**EDIT2:**

**post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :post_id, :title_name, :total_items, :user_id

  validates :title_name, :presence => true, :length => { :in => 1..50 }

  belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => 'post_id'

  self.primary_key = :post_id

  def to_param
    "#{post_id}"
  end
end
```

Comment: @rudolph9 i can't find any option to use that can change how the errors are shown via the gem api that's why i posted it here guessing that someone may have had the same problem before...

Comment: Thats an interesting question.  Looking at the [example app](http://bipapp.heroku.com/users/67#), if you put in _one_ character for the `last_name` it return the error "Last name has invalid length", where the entry in the table is `last_name`.

Comment: going ahead and cloning the example and refracting `last_name` to `last_curseword`, the app now produces the output "Last curseword has invalid length".

Comment: i am also searching the code on github but i can't find anything whats different than my app on the way i use the gem... still searching

Comment: i have edited the question with the differences i found in the ajax response... this could be the problem but im not sure...

Comment: updated question to include the model

Comment: ok, made my answer specific to your model.  Does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

i found that best_in_place gem uses the following method to display the errors when the save was not completed

```
respond_with_bip(@user
```

which was attached to the `format.json` as

```
format.json { respond_with_bip(@user) }
```

so replacing the way i show the errors via json with this code solved the problem.

Comment: Nice!  Is this how they are changing it by default in the example app?

Comment: Is it a rails function or something included with the gem?

Comment: i am not sure...i searched for it using sublime find in folder option but it couldn't locate it... i guess its inside the gem

Answer (score 0):

This is actually really simple, and has nothing to do with the **best_in_pace** gem.

Modify the file **config/locales/en.yml** with:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    models:
      attributes:
        post:
          title_name: 'Title name'
```

Now the attribute `title_name` should be replace with the string `'Title name'` in your view.

**Note**: The method listed above overrides the default, it does *not* set the default.

Comment: since my model is `Post` and the column name is `title_name` shouldn't the `user` be `post` and `last_name` be `title_name` in your code above? i tried it but still, it doesn't seem to work... also in the code example in github there isnt anything inside the locales

Comment: Can you double check?  I revised what I had before (forgot to change out some things)... And the file _is_ indeed there in [the example included with the gem](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place/blob/master/test_app/config/locales/en.yml)